# Definition of continuity up to the boundary

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and bounded. What does it mean $f\in C(\bar{\Omega})$, i.e. what does it mean $f$ to be continuous at $x \in \partial \Omega$, maybe
$$\forall \epsilon >0 \quad \exists \delta >0 \quad \text{s.t.} \quad y \in \partial \Omega \cap B_\delta(x) \quad \implies |f(y)-f(x)| < \delta \quad ?$$

Also $$C^k(\bar{\Omega})=\{f \in C^k(\Omega) : \partial^{\alpha} f \ \ \text{has continuous extension to} \ \ \bar{\Omega}, \ \ \ \forall |\alpha| \leq k\}$$

Does this mean there exists a function $f_{\alpha} \in C(\bar{\Omega})$ s.t. $f_{\alpha}(x) = \partial^{\alpha} f(x)$ for any $x \in \Omega$ ?

Why is this definition given for $\Omega$ bounded? Can't this be defined for any open $\Omega$? Thank you!

Comment: Hmm I would adjust your definition to have $\overline{\Omega}\cap B_{\delta}(x)$ instead. (You *would* like to approach $y$ from anywhere in $\Omega$, not just on the boundary. Also the reason you don't do it for unbounded $\Omega$ is that you might have to evaluate your function at infinity.. That can get into some very murky water very fast.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of continuity at a point $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is just that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $\|x-p\| < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(p)| < \epsilon$. The worry may be that $x$ could be anywhere in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but it can only be anywhere in $\overline{\Omega}$, or else $f(x)$ will not exist. This applies regardless of whether $p$ is on $\partial \Omega$.

Note that $f \in C(\overline{\Omega})$ means that $f$ is already defined on $\Omega$, so there's no worry that $f(p)$ exists either.

Also, your interpretation of $C^k(\overline{\Omega})$ seems correct to me.

Finally, in my mind $C(\overline{\Omega})$ can be defined for any open $\Omega$, but it's possible that $C^k(\overline{\Omega})$ may be trickier. As Cameron Williams said in his comment, things can get weird at infinity.